# Reading a specific number of randomly-chosen json entries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

Python3/Jupyter Notebook question. I have a large json (> 3 million entries). I'm trying to read 50,000 random entries into a list, with the requirement that these random entries have the "country_code" parameter of a specific value. Right now I am reading each of the 3 million entries, narrowing down to the entries with the right country code, and then taking 50,000 random elements from that sublist. I'd like to only read 50,000 random lines with the correct country code instead of having to go through all 3 million first. The current method is taking way too long.

My current code:

```
def filter_json_by_country(filename, country):
    file = Path(filename)
    data = list()
    
    with file.open('r') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line))

    loc_filtered_data = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if len(data[i]['user_location']) != 0 and data[i]['user_location']['country_code'] == country:
            loc_filtered_data.append(data[i])

    ids = [loc_filtered_data[i]['tweet_id'] for i in range(len(loc_filtered_data))]
    ids = random.sample(ids, 50000) 
    return ids
```

EDITED -- json sample:

```
{
     "tweet_id":"1231698465102663680",
     "created_at":"Sun Feb 23 21:52:52 +0000 2020",
     "user_id":"433036746",
     "geo_source":"tweet_text",
     "user_location":{},
     "geo":{},
     "place":{},
     "tweet_locations":
        [
            {
                "country_code":"us",
                "state":"Illinois"},
            {
                "country_code":"fr",
                "state":"Auvergne-Rh\u00f4ne-Alpes",
                "county":"Die"},
            {
                "country_code":"it",
                "state":"Piemont",
                "county":"TO",
                "city":"Porte"},
            {
                "country_code":"fr",
                "state":"Occitania",
                "county":"Castres",
                "city":"Lacaze"},
            {
                "country_code":"br",
                "state":"Sergipe",
                "county":"Microrregi\u00e3o do Baixo S\u00e3o Francisco Sergipano",
                "city":"Propri\u00e1"}
        ]
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE or code editor unless your question is specifically related to the editor itself.

Comment: This would probably be much more efficiently accomplished if you loaded your JSON data into a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: could you provide a sample json?

Comment: @MZ yep, just updated

Comment: @jsd191 take a look at my answer below, see if they help. And did you prettify that JSON or are they all in several lines – because how then does `data = json.loads(line)` return something valid then?

Comment: @MZ they did help, thank you!! (yes, I prettified the json.)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix that decreases time linearly:

```py
def filter_json_by_country(filename, country):
    file = Path(filename)
    loc_filtered_data = []

    with file.open('r') as f:
        for line in f:
            data = json.loads(line)
            if len(data['user_location']) != 0 and data['user_location']['country_code'] == country:
                loc_filtered_data.append(data)
        

    ids = [loc_filtered_data[i]['tweet_id'] for i in range(len(loc_filtered_data))]
    ids = random.sample(ids, 50000) 
    return ids
```

This adds the data if and only if it already satisfies it, so you reduce the number of times you need to iterate through all your JSON data.

Here's one that incorporates randomization into the same loop as well:

```py
def filter_json_by_country(filename, country):    
    loc_filtered_data = []
    length = -1
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for length, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
        
        # Do randomizing before loading json
        shuffled = list(range(length + 1))
        random.shuffle(shuffled)

        for i in shuffled:
            if len(loc_filtered_data) >= 50_000:
                break
            f.seek(i, 0)
            data = json.loads(f.readline())
            
            # only append data if it satisfy the requirements
            if len(data['user_location']) != 0 and data['user_location']['country_code'] == country:
                loc_filtered_data.append(data[i])

    ids = [loc_filtered_data[i]['tweet_id'] for i in range(len(loc_filtered_data))]
    
    return ids
```

The speed of `seek`ing is machine dependent. If you're able to determine the number of lines in a file faster than this, it'll be even faster. But the idea here is that you'll only need to iterate through exactly 50,000 valid entries (more if there are invalid entries).

Answer (score -1):

Why use line-separated json?

If you time your function it is likely loading the json that takes 99% of the time.  Have you considered using some sort of table that would allow arbitrary access, rather than forcing you to filter afterwards?

If you must keep the json format, try loading it up, pickling it down, and then loading the pickled file, I have seen reasonable performance doing smart caching like that.

As another alternative, try looking for the country code before parsing with json (substring search, or even 'grep').